# Probability of buses passing along the street.

Tags: probability

$60$ buses pass along the street daily. Of these, $15$ are express buses. Determine the probability that between $5$ buses that follow one after the other at least $2$ are express buses.

I tried

$P(express)=15/60=0.25$

$P(not express)=45/60=0.75$

Then I calculate (5 of 60) multiply $(0.25)^2*(0.75)^(58)$

I don't know if this makes any sense.

The result should be $0.3673$ but with this way I tried I can't get it

Comment: You probably intended to imply that the order of the $60$ buses is distributed uniformly over all possibly orders? In that case Mroog's answer seems to be correct, and it yields approximately $0.3671$, so there seems to be an error either in the answer you were given or in Mroog's and my understanding of the question.

Comment: @joriki What about my answer ?

Comment: @calculus: It gives the same result (as it should). (I hadn't checked it because it seemed more complicated to me and you hadn't written it out in a form that I could simply paste into Wolfram|Alpha :-)

Comment: I like to answer more fundamental, if I have the Impression that the questioner is not common with these exercises. I added the link to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Count the ways to have at least 2 express buses out of 5 and divide by the ways to have 5 buses from the 60 total:

\begin{align}
\frac{{45 \choose 3}{15 \choose 2} + {45 \choose 2}{15 \choose 3} + {45 \choose 1}{15 \choose 4} + {45 \choose 0}{15 \choose 5}}{{60 \choose 5}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

First you can use the converse proability:

Lex x be the number of express busses among 5 buses.

Then $P(X\geq 2)=1-P(X \leq 1)=1-P(X=1)-P(X=0)$

The ways that 1 express bus (e) is among 5 buses (b) are:

$ebbbb$

$bebbb$

$bbebb$

$bbbeb$

$bbbbe$

The probability for one of these ways is

$\frac{15}{60}\cdot \frac{45}{59} \cdot \frac{44}{58} \cdot \frac{43}{57} \cdot\frac{42}{56} $

Therefore $P(X=1)=5\cdot \frac{15}{60}\cdot \frac{45}{59} \cdot \frac{44}{58} \cdot \frac{43}{57} \cdot\frac{42}{56}$

One way that no express bus is among 5 buses:

$bbbbb$

Can you evaluate $P(X=0)$ ?

Here is the [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1-%285*%5Cfrac%7B15%7D%7B60%7D%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac%7B45%7D%7B59%7D%20%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac%7B44%7D%7B58%7D%20%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac%7B43%7D%7B57%7D%20%5Ccdot%5Cfrac%7B42%7D%7B56%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B41%7D%7B60%7D%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac%7B45%7D%7B59%7D%20%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac%7B44%7D%7B58%7D%20%5Ccdot%20%5Cfrac%7B43%7D%7B57%7D%20%5Ccdot%5Cfrac%7B42%7D%7B56%7D%29) to the whole calculation.

Comment: After you saw one non-express bus the probability for the next one to be non-express is $\frac{44}{59}$ and not $\frac{45}{60}$.

Comment: You are right. It is an hypergeometric distribution.